# How to make relationship absolute div with parent div parent

Tags: css, position, absolute

I have three divs

```
.tableContainer {
position:relative;
height: 120px;
}
.container {
 position:relative;
 width: auto;
 height: auto;
}
.viewsp div3 {
position: absolute;
background: transparent;
padding: .2em 0px;
top: -22px;
text-align: left;
margin-left: -25px;
line-height: normal; 
}
```

[image]

i want make div3(absolute) relation ship with tableContainer. i want fix the position od div3. but it's going top of the page

Answer (score 0):

The absolute position depend on the first relative parent control.
You have to put your div3 inside the tableContainer.

**Edit :**

if i understand what you need is a header that keept at the top of the table will you scrolling to view the data. You can achieve this by doing the following.

```
<div style="position:relative">
    <table id="scroll" style="position:absolute;z-index:10">
        <th>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
        </th>
    </table>
    <table>
        <tr>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
        </tr>
         //... many row   
    </table>
</div>
```

you just have to modify the top of the scroll table as you scroll the div.

Comment: there is no chance to keep like this as per my requirement

Comment: where is the div3 ? you can make is parent relative and try to modify the left, top to put it where you want.

Comment: that div3 in th. if i give out side it'll not working body data. My    requirement is fixed head data with scrollable data which is have smooth scroll bar

Answer (score 0):

(Parent) - `position: relative;`

(Child) - `position: absolute;`